Is this baseboard installation a good job?
We had new baseboards installed (alongside our new floor). The result looked surprisingly rough to our eyes but we have no notion about what to expect. The installer and floor store told us that this is perfectly normal -- we just have to caulk and paint.
If anyone out here is knowledgeable about this, we would really appreciate their opinion.










Thanks!

I'm no expert, but those corners look really bad.

that is awful. post those pictures in store google review

Working carpenter here… this is bottom of the barrel work. If a junior where I work did this, we’d remove and replace without question. Don’t pay.

This is worse than the very first time I did it, and I used a bargain basement hand mitre saw in a house where nothing is square

In addition to the obvious, the nail holes aren't puttied, the top seam where the top of the baseboard meets the wall isn't caulked and it needs a coat of paint however - it's no where near ready to paint.

While most will agree with the consensus here that this is sub-par, this question is off topic as opinion-based. There is no objective measure of how much caulk is acceptable. My fellow long-timers know this but apparently can't resist weighing in. They should also VTC instead of grabbing rep.

no quarter rounds?

@JGH, quarter rounds? It looks like they put new baseboard in on top of a new flooring install. Quarter rounds are for when you don't want to go to that effort, no?

"Caulk and paint make me the carpenter I ain't"

I wouldn't accept that from myself as DIY job (and I only touch tools when I move or something breaks). So if you paid for that, I'd certainly expect better.

A lot of those edges are torn up pretty badly. He may have been using the wrong saw/blade for this material. I see lots of pencil marks, but they rarely line up with any of the cuts. Some of the pics hint that your walls aren't flat or plumb, but even with that extra complication these cuts definitely could have been done a lot better.

@isherwood: I think the real question here is whether the work is sufficiently bad as to justify withholding payment unless or until the work is redone.  While it's impossible to predict how any particular judge or jury would view things, I think the question of whether work is so bad that a reasonable person could reject it, or good enough that a reasonable person may be justified in grumbling, but not in refusing payment, is somewhat objective.

@supercat, none of that matters. It's either an assessment of quality (a purely subjective thing), or an matter of a legal contract. Both are off topic here.

@isherwood: Even from a legal standpoint, the first relevant determination would be whether the work is consistent with what a competent tradesperson should be expected to produce, and a question-and-answers forum for people doing such work would seem the most appropriate place to answer tat.   Questions about what to do if (as in this case) it isn't would be legal questions better addressed on the law stackexchange, but if the person had posted photos where the pieces touched, but one extended 0.25mm past the other, there would be no point in asking a question on law.stackexchange.com.

@isherwood: On the flip side, if someone wanted to ensure that neither piece would prototrude more than some amount, it might be reasonable to ask wehther such a thing should be specified in the work order (probably a good idea if one wants to ensure alignment within e.g. 0.1mm), or whether such a spec would be seen as insulting (e.g. if one wanted to ensure that neither side would protrude by more than 5mm).

You make reasonable points, but there's a ton of precedent for this policy on this site. I'm voting according to my knowledge of that.

Some contractor work success is in the eye of the beholder, but this is just plain unacceptable.  This person does this for a living?  The contractor works for the flooring store?  If so, post reviews of the experience to warn others at least.  Has the store seen these photos?

Yes this was done by a professional floor installer subcontracted by the floor store. The vendor from the floor store saw the work in person and told us it was perfectly fine.
Thanks to the asnwers here, I feel better equipped for a follow up chat with them and for posting a review. Thanks!

Haha, what a joke.  POOR is the only word to describe that work.   People typically do a relatively worse job on paint projects, because caulk does fill gaps, but outside corners really need to be tight.  You can try rolling the edge of a screwdriver shaft along those corners to try and mold the thin edges close together before caulking if you need to.

"The vendor from the floor store saw the work in person and told us it was perfectly fine", sounds like they're gaslighting you so they don't have to rework it.

This wouldn't be acceptable for a DIYer let alone a professional. My guess is that his/her miter saw guide needs adjustment/cailbration or that the angles are correct but the walls are out plumb and not square. The installer should have at least done the caulking  to cover the lousy job. Take some pictures and show them to the company the installer works for. Withhold final payment until they correct it.

Not only are the miter joints poor, but in some of the photos the lengths of the pieces are way off.

I totally agree that this job is pisspoor. Hence a Q: If "the walls are out of plumb and corners not square", shouldn't that be adjusted for?

@Astrogator  Most certainly, but not by the guy doing the floor and baseboards. There are ways, tools, to measure the angles when they are not sharp 90's.  Sometimes you need to go back to the old fashion coping saw to get the right fit to a badly installed wall.

I know the point of this thread is to dunk on this terrible install, but it would be good to know how to get a tight joint on an outside corner that isn't exact 90 degrees.  And I thought all inside corners should be coped to accommodate movement without showing gaps.

@JimmyJames — that would make a good question. (Short version: fiddle with outside corners until you get them right, then discover that the piece is too short and repeat.)

@AloysiusDefenestrate Actually I remembered a solution for this.  Place two straight boards along each wall so they cross and then mark the bottom one along the edges of the intersection.  You can then bisect the angle to get your blade angle.  The other trick I recall is to flip one of the boards over and cut it on the opposite side of the blade which will account for error in your angle.

If the walls aren't 90 degrees, you can do a lazy job and leave a gap inside the join.  Not at the point of the join. The whole point of baseboards is to cover up open joins (at the wall-floor junction). The baseboard and cornice are the decorative thing that is supposed to be done right, to cover up rough carpentry.

This would be acceptable was it 13-year old building their treetop house.

Pieces lengths are obviously off
Angles are off too
Vertical alignment is almost non-existent
Uncovered nails
Dirty surface

Demand the rework. Warn others not to use their services.

This is ****. Sorry, I can't be more positive than that.
I've just installed a load of skirting - as a DIYer who has only done it once before, using consumer grade tools, in a 1950s house with walls about as straight as a banana - and it looked SIGNIFICANTLY better than this, even before caulking.
If I was paying a professional to do it, I would expect it to be done to a professional standard, not look like it was done by the work-experience kid after a few pints!! They should have caulked it at the very least (although even that would be a bodge job, as those cuts are very poor).
In the UK at least, you would need to give them a reasonable opportunity to sort it out (free of charge of course) before you can start looking at legal remedies, but I'd certainly be documenting everything, and withholding payment until you're happy with it.
This is exactly why I do all my own home renovation work (unless legally unable to do so, e.g. gas and major electrical work, or the costs of tools/equipment would be prohibitively/disproportionately high); I realise it's obviously not possible for everyone due to a variety of reasons, but from my experience, finding a decent tradesman who actually does a good job and takes pride in their work is the exception rather than the norm (anyone fresh out of school can buy an old van, spend £50 on some vinyl lettering, and call themselves a painter & decorator).
It might take a bit longer to get things done - due to needing to fit it around work & kids - but at least I know it will be done to a standard I'm happy with (and probably cheaper!)

This is a tad worse than the quality that was done when my townhouse was built. A lot of caulk was used to make it marginally acceptable. A lot of that caulk needs to be redone 20 years later
